# Unable to convert Json to POJO using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

Here is my response:

```
{
  "orderPlacedData": {
    "createdAt": "2022-06-22T00:34:25.833Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2022-06-22T00:34:25.833Z",
    "orderId": "62b26391e5ddd5001620cd07",
    "orderedItems": {
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 654,
      "id": "61f4da753627fc0016dfec5a"
    },
    "userId": "6294d73a789e677d84d8e282",
    "status": "PENDING_CONFIRMATION"
  }
}
```

Here are my data classes:

```
@Parcelize
data class OrderRecievedData(
    val orderPlacedData: OrderPlacedData
):Parcelable


@Parcelize
data class OrderPlacedData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val orderId: String,
    val status: String,
    var userId: String,
    val orderedItems: OrderPlaceDataItem,
    val createdAt: String,
    val lastUpdated: String
) : Parcelable 


@Parcelize
data class OrderPlaceDataItem(
    val id: String,
    val quantity: Int,
    val price:Int
) : Parcelable
```

I'm trying to convert the above string to POJO but I'm getting this **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 21 path $.orderPlacedData**

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since my Json is beginning from a { not a ".

My code for converting the above string to POJO:

```
val data = try {
        val jsonString = Gson().toJson(message.data)
        Gson().fromJson(jsonString,OrderRecievedData::class.java)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: exception $e")
        null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved what the problem was. I was converting the data to Json before converting it to POJO. But since I was already getting the data as Json I just needed it to convert it to string and it worked.

```
val data = try {
    Gson().fromJson(message.data.toString(),OrderRecievedData::class.java)

} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: exception $e")
    null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
data class OrderRecievedData(
    val orderPlacedData: OrderPlacedData
)

data class OrderPlacedData (
    val createdAt: String,
    val lastUpdated: String,

    @Json(name = "orderId")
    val orderID: String,

    val orderedItems: OrderedItems,

    @Json(name = "userId")
    val userID: String,

    val status: String
)

data class OrderedItems (
    val quantity: Int,
    val price: Int,
    val id: String
)
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

use this data class

```
data class Response(
    @field:SerializedName("orderPlacedData")
    val orderPlacedData: OrderPlacedData? = null
)

data class OrderPlacedData(

    @field:SerializedName("createdAt")
    val createdAt: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("lastUpdated")
    val lastUpdated: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("orderId")
    val orderId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("orderedItems")
    val orderedItems: OrderedItems? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("userId")
    val userId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status")
    val status: String? = null
)

data class OrderedItems(

    @field:SerializedName("quantity")
    val quantity: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("price")
    val price: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same error.

Comment: check your API response, I think a problem with your API.